# JQuery - How to convert html with br's in it to html with p's in it?

Tags: jquery

On the my page I have html like this:

```
hi<br>bye<br>sigh<br>hello <em>tie</em><br>lie
```

with jquery, how can I convert it to html like this (basically using p's instead of br's):

```
<p>hi</p><p>bye</p><p>sigh</p><p>hello <em>tie</em></p><p>lie</p>
```

My first attempt at doing this was this code:

```
$(container).contents().filter(function() {
                var val = this.nodeValue;
                return this.nodeType == TEXT_NODE && $.trim(val).length > 0;
            })
            .wrap('<p></p>')
            .end()
            .filter('br')
            .remove();
```

This worked for the most part, except that `hello` and `<em>tie</em>` would not be in the same `p` element.

Does anyone know how I can do this properly?

Comment: How does the code get messed up like that in the first place? I know I've seen this happen in Google Docs with Firefox, but I assume that's not how you write your pages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple javascript solution

```
var obj = document.getElementById('container'),
    str = obj.innerHTML,
    ar = str.split('<br />'),
    result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++)
{
 result += '<p>' + ar[i] + '</p>';
}
obj.innerHTML = result;
```

I don't know how to do this with jQuery...

Comment: It is do-able in jQuery, but its going to be longer than this anyways.  Sometimes the library doesn't help.

Comment: A lot of people don't know the difference anymore.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/2657095#2657095

Comment: No. When you fetch `innerHTML` the browser may give you a `br` tag in various different serialisation formats. You are likely to get `<br>` or `<BR>` or even conceivably `<br/>`, but nothing would give you `<br />`.

Comment: yes probably you are right, but if you want more advanced version you can use Regular expression for splitting string. I have just added example how to solve one problem. with regex you can split string like this (<br>)|(<BR>)|(<br />)|(<BR />) I'm not so sure is this working now, i don't have time to check but this should be probably right answer.

Comment: (If you've touched the element's data with jQuery, you could even get `<BR jQuery123=456>` in IE...)

Comment: you can write regular expression for catching br tag with any attribute in it. if you need help writing regex I can help you later, now I need to sleep, working day tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You were along the right lines, only there's not a convenient way(*) to wrap a range of children rather than just one at a time. You'd have to do it yourself, eg.:

```
// Take a range of children in a parent element and wrap them in a new element.
//
function wrapChildren(tagname, parent, child0, child1) {
    var wrapper= document.createElement(tagname);
    for (var i= child1-child0; i-->0;)
        wrapper.appendChild(parent.childNodes[child0]);
    parent.insertBefore(wrapper, parent.childNodes[child0]);
}

// Find `<br>`s and wrap the stretches between them.
//
var container= document.getElementById('container');
var lastbr= container.childNodes.length;
for (var i= lastbr; i-->0;) {
    var child= container.childNodes[i];
    if (child.nodeType===1 && child.tagName.toLowerCase()==='br') {
        wrapChildren('p', container, i+1, lastbr);
        container.removeChild(child);
        lastbr= i;
    }
}
wrapChildren('p', container, 0, lastbr);
```

(*: jQuery or otherwise. Well, there *is* `surroundContents` in DOM Range, but support is poor.)

Comment: hmm, I hadn't spotted that one. You can *nearly* do it very nicely with `wrapAll`+`nextUntil`, except that it won't select the text nodes (a lot of jQuery can't do anything with text nodes, unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

```
'<p>'+html.replace(/<br\s?\/?>/gi,'</p><p>')+'</p>'
```

never tested. but thats the idea.

Comment: This isn't "doing it with jQuery" but it gets my vote anyway.